# Security for Users added in the Case Team Role

Tags: security, access, case-teams

I am trying to understand the impact on the visibility/access on case record with Case Team Role. So I have the below scenario -

- OWD for Case is "**Private**"
- Case Owner is User: "XXX" having the profile - "YYY", wherein Profile "YYY" is having "Read" access to Case object.
- Same User "XXX" is part of predefined Case Team having a Case Team Role with Access as "Read/Write"
- The above pre-defined Case Team is added to the case.

In this scenario, what type of access, user "XXX" will have in that case?

- Read Only
- Read/Write

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 things we need to keep in mind:

1. Visibility (Record level)
2. Access rights (Profile Permissions)

According to OWD, case is `Private`, the `XXX` get visibility of the record and the access right (Read\Write) due to Pre-defined case team role on that particular Case record.

Now, `XXX` user will have read\write access to that record, only if you provide **Read** and **Edit** permission on the Case object.

> Thumb rule is, access gained from Sharing rule, user managed sharing, apex managed sharing, case team will not comes into play until and unless, user gets access to object and fields through Profiles or permission sets.

User with Modify All data permission supersedes everything.

One last thing, Case Comments will always have **read\write** access even if user has **read** access to the Case object, because CaseComment does not inherit access from Case object

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for sharing the information on Case Comments. I was not aware of this one.

Comment: Intentionally shared, because case comments does not inherit access from Case object

Answer (score 1):

Case team provides record access, just like manual sharing would.

They still need profile / permission set edit access on case object else they will have no access to the case, because they have no access to the case object.

They also would need field level read/edit access on any fields they need to read / edit.

Comment: Got it. So even if the case team is providing edit access to the user, but since the profile is having no edit access, the user will not get the edit permission on the case. Correct?

Comment: Yes, because Case team is providing edit access to the record only. User needs access to record, object, and fields to be able to edit / read.